# Vue3/Inertia Failed to resolve component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a application which is built with the VILT-stack (Vue, Inertia, Laravel, Tailwind). I have some components like `cards` which could be used everywhere in the application. Because I don't want to manually import these components every time I built a function that registers the components in certain directories:

```
/**
 * Register components from the ./components and ./components/core
 * directories. This way these components don't have to be imported
 * manually every time.
 *
 * @param {Vue instance} app
 */
function registerGlobalComponents (app) {
  const requireComponent = require.context(
    './components' || './components/core',
    true,
    /\.vue$/
  );

  for (const file of requireComponent.keys()) {
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(file);
    const name = file
      .replace(/index.js/, '')
      .replace(/^\.\//, '')
      .replace(/\.\w+$/, '');
    const componentName = upperFirst(camelCase(name));

    app.component(componentName,
      componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
  }
}
```

The creation of the inertia app happens in the same file:

```
/**
 * Create an Inertia app instance.
 */
createInertiaApp({
  resolve: (name) => import(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup ({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
    const vueApp = createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) });

    /**
     * Mixin for showing notifications.
     */
    vueApp.mixin({
      data: function () {
        return {};
      },
      computed: {
        pageNotifications () {
          return this.$page.props.notification;
        }
      }
    });

    vueApp.use(plugin).mount(el);
    registerGlobalComponents(vueApp);
  }
});
```

Because my `card` component is in the `/components/core` directory I have to call the component in the `template` tag like this: `<core-card> content </core-card>`. Now my card is perfectly showing on the page as you can see in the image. [image]

But somehow I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: core-card

I get this warning for all my other components that are registered through this `registerGlobalComponents()` function. Why do I get this warning when my components are showing correctly and working fine?

Comment: FYI someone does this manually here using import statements alone: [Register vue component globally on inertia/vue instance](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/203#issuecomment-836727766) - your generic implementation might work but does the static approach give the same message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem why I got this error was because I was mounting the app before I registered the components. This resulted in the components being shown in my application but still getting the warning that the component couldn't be found. By importing the components **before** the mount this problem was solved.

I previously imported the components this way:

```
    createInertiaApp({
      resolve: (name) => import(`./Pages/${name}`),
      setup ({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        const vueApp = createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) });
    
        /**
         * Mixin for showing notifications.
         */
        vueApp.mixin({
          data: function () {
            return {};
          },
          computed: {
            pageNotifications () {
              return this.$page.props.notification;
            }
          }
        });
    
        vueApp.use(plugin).mount(el);
        registerGlobalComponents(vueApp);
      }
    });
```

And changed the order of calling `plugin`, `registerGlobalComponents` and the `mount` of the app like this:

```
vueApp.use(plugin);
registerGlobalComponents(vueApp);
vueApp.mount(el);
```

I was able to fix this problem thanks to Robert from the official Inertia Discord. If he wants to claim the bounty I will definitely award him the points.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but for me, it only changed when I changed the vue route:

```
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
```

to

```
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
```